# How to connect to IONOS cloud storage with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cloud, storage, ionos

I am a beginner in programing. I want to access my S3 storage in IONOS with a c# ASP.NET Core web-API program. I don't know which Nuget-Packet should I install and how to define for c# the 'Endpoint', that is given in Ionos documentaions.
Thanks a lot for your helps

I have tried with AWSSDK.S3 packet. But was unsuccessfull!

Comment: Do you need to use the IONOS API? https://api.ionos.com/docs/s3/v2/

Comment: yes,   I could  not get useful informations in WebSite.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the Nuget Package 'Minio'. It works with S3 compatible storage such as IONOS.
It has a good [documentation](https://docs.min.io/docs/dotnet-client-quickstart-guide.html).